# How to use @param query String used to filter the Messages listed. Any code example?

Tags: android, gmail-api

I explore gmail API documentation, but unfortunately i cannot find any code's example with *@param query String used to filter the Messages listed.*

In the code below I successfully get messages list from Label "INBOX", but i need to use filter for getting messages which were sent from some certain email

*(for example: no-reply@accounts.google.com)*.

I considered the code example on [GMAIL API Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), but i didn't find there how to use @param query. Unfortunately i don't have enough experience to understand that on my own.

```
    /**
     * List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.
     * @param mService Authorized Gmail API instance.
     * @param user User's email address. The special value "me"
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @param query String used to filter the Messages listed.
     * @param labelIds Only return Messages with these labelIds applied.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message> getMessagesList() throws IOException {
        String user = "me";

        ListLabelsResponse listLabelsResponse =
                mService.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<String> labelIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Label label : listLabelsResponse.getLabels()) {
            if (label.getId() == "INBOX")
                labelIds.add(label.getId());
        }

        ListMessagesResponse listMessagesResponse = mService.users().messages()
                                                    .list(user)
                                                    .setLabelIds(labelIds)
                                             //     .setQ(query)
                                                    .execute();

        List<com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        while(listMessagesResponse.getMessages() != null){
            messages.addAll(listMessagesResponse.getMessages());
            if(listMessagesResponse.getNextPageToken() != null){
                String pageToken = listMessagesResponse.getNextPageToken();

                listMessagesResponse = mService.users().messages()
                                        .list(user)
                                        .setLabelIds(labelIds)
                               //       .setQ(query)
                                        .setPageToken(pageToken)
                                        .execute();

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message message : messages)
            Log.d(TAG, message.toPrettyString());

        return messages;
    }
```

When i try to uncomment the line `.setQ(query)` then i get an error

```
E/#: The following error occurred:
     403 Forbidden
     {
       "code" : 403,
       "errors" : [ {
         "domain" : "global",
         "message" : "Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter",
         "reason" : "forbidden"
       } ],
       "message" : "Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter"
     }
```

However i've added all neccessary SCOPES such as

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,
                                         GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY,
                                         GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM,
                                         GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,
                                         GmailScopes.GMAIL_METADATA,
};
```

Please, can anybody help me,

How to use @param query used to filter the Messages from some sender's email? Thank you!

Comment: Don't have codes for you, but if your looking on how to use the query parameter, you can use the [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) for a list of valid filters. What you're looking for is also mentioned there, messages from a 'specific sender' using the filter 'from:'.

Comment: Thanx! There are no any relation to code and Gmail API in that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out!

1. So first of all, to use param query I had to exclude the final
   String `GmailScopes.GMAIL_METADATA` from SCOPE collection then
   reinstall(rebuild) my app and reauthorize in my client app.
2. Regarding query param: in order to my case I just had to create next
       code lines:

   ```
   String query = "label:inbox from:no-reply@accounts.google.com is:unread";
   ```

   and put that query into `setQ()` method

   ```
       listMessagesResponse = mService.users().messages()
                                              .list(user)
                                              .setQ(query)
                                              .setPageToken(pageToken)
                                              .execute();
   ```

That's all! At least those steps helped me.